# Left outer join using Seq ,Tuple and Streams using jool java 8

Tags: java, tuples, left-join, jooq, seq

I have two Lists Customers and Address which have pmtxnid as a common value . 
I want to use jool(java 8) leftouterjoin method but I am no aware about the correct syntax . Also there is no example by which I can understand it in a simpler way . 
Please help if anyone knows about Seq,Tuples jool with java 8 Streams.

```
List<Customers> customers = new ArrayList<Customers>();
    customers.add(new Customers(16079391, 12, "A")); // NULL
    customers.add(new Customers(16079392, 13, "B")); // 2
    customers.add(new Customers(16079393, 14, "C")); // NULL
    customers.add(new Customers(16079394, 15, "D")); // BIll
    customers.add(new Customers(16079395, 16, "E")); // 1

    List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
    addresses.add(new Address(1, 16079392, "bangalore", "karnataka"));
    addresses.add(new Address(2, 16079392, "chennai", "tamil nadu"));
    addresses.add(new Address(3, 16079392, "hyderabad", "telanagana"));
    addresses.add(new Address(4, 16079395, "indore", "mp"));
    addresses.add(new Address(5, 16079395, "kanpur", "up"));

Seq<List<Customers>> s1 = Seq.of(customers);
    Seq<List<Address>> s2 = Seq.of(addresses);
```

I tried the below code but no success.

```
Seq<Tuple2<Seq<List<Customers>>, Seq<List<Address>>>> loj=  Seq.of(s1).leftOuterJoin(Seq.of(s2), (t, u) -> Objects.equals(t, u));
```

Comment: Isn't this the same question that you've been asking for a while now?

Comment: yes but i have not got any perfect solution till now for the same..

Comment: other than this i am trying different ways to check it

Comment: Just ask ChatGPT. Seq.seq(customers) is the method

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the common `pmtxnid` value is accessible using `Customers#getPmtxnid()` and `Address#getPmtxnid()` respectively, the `leftOuterJoin()` call should look something like this:

```java
var result = Seq.of(s1).leftOuterJoin(Seq.of(s2),
    (c, a) -> Objects.equals(c.getPmtxnid(), a.getPmtxnid()));
```

Note that `Objects#equals()` is only necessary if either of the objects can have a `null` pmtxnid.